# inserir texto personalizado no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um textarea que o usuário pode definir tamanho da fonte, a própria fonte do texto e inserir imagens. Minha pergunta e como passar esse texto personalizado para o MySQL.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara "o usuário pode definir tamanho da fonte, a própria fonte do texto e inserir imagens", como ele faz isso? Normalmente se utiliza BBCode ou Markdown, *o Stackoverflow usa este último por exemplo*. Você salva no banco de dados normalmente, depois no caso do BBCode [existe `bbcode_create` e `bbcode_parse`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.bbcode-create.php), que converte para HTML, justamente para  que possa exibir.

Comment: teria que ver como o usuário escolhe essas propriedades, mas, pensando de uma forma mais simples, você pode armazenar o conteúdo em html diretamente para exibição posterior, ou, armazenar essas propriedades além do texto. Eu faria desta última forma, mas ainda assim teria que saber mais detalhes do seu projeto.

Comment: Eu tenho no meu banco uma coluna do tipo blob para inserir os textos ou texto com imagem nesse caso funciona o único problema e na hora de pegar o valor com ajax que ele pega somente o texto o style que fica definido no textarea(color , font-size, font-family) ele não consegue pegar. Eu já fiz isso no c# transforma tudo em binário, mas no c# ele reconhecia o style e passava tudo para o banco resumindo meu problema quando tento pegar o valor com jquery ele pega a string limpo e seco.